# glsl arithmetic operator

Tags: opengl, glsl

Why does this line:

```
float x = 1 - gl_Color.x;
```

give:

```
(26): error: Could not implicitly convert operands to arithmetic operator
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

GLSL (prior to #version 120) does not allow implicit conversions between integer and floating point.  `1` is an integer and `gl_Color.x` is a float, so you get an error.  You need

```
float x = 1.0 - gl_Color.x;
```

instead